# Copying an extra columns rows across if there is a match but ignoring subsequent like matches

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 spreadsheets:

main.xlsxm

[image]

drs.xlsx

[image]

At the moment:

> If column value E in drs.xlsx equals column value A in main.xlsx: Then
>   on the matching row in main.xlsx Copy column value B in drs.xls to
>   column value J in main.xlsx
>
> If a second match is found (provided it is not the same as the first
>   match): Where column value E in drs.xlsx equals column value A in
>   main.xlsx Copy column value B in drs.xls to column value K in
>   main.xlsx
>
> If a third match is found (provided it is not the same as the first
>   and second match): Where column value E in drs.xlsx equals column
>   value A in main.xlsx Copy column value B in drs.xls to column value L
>   in main.xlsx

This is handled by the following code:

```
Sub drs_Update()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim user As Range

    Dim lastrowdrs As Long, lastrowMAIN As Long
    Dim rng As Range, res As Range
    Dim k As Byte
    Dim fAddr As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Specify sheet name for Main wb
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

    ' Open drs
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Working\drs.xlsx")

    ' Specify sheet name for drs wb
    Set sh2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With sh1
        ' Find last row on column A in the Main wb
        lastrowMAIN = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' Clear previous data in columns J:L
        '.Range("J1:L" & lastrowMAIN).ClearContents
    End With

    With sh2
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        ' Find last row on column A in drs wb
        lastrowdrs = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        ' Apply filter
        With .Range("A1:D1")
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("TW", "W", "L", "V"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Microsoft Windows XP Professional"
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Windows 7", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Windows XP"
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Workstation-Windows"
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        ' Get only visible rows in column E
        Set rng = .Range("E1:E" & lastrowdrs).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0

        ' Loop through every user in Main wb
        For Each user In sh1.Range("A1:A" & lastrowMAIN)
            ' Counter for finding entries
            k = 0
            ' Find first match
            Set res = rng.Find(What:=user.Value, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not res Is Nothing Then
                ' Remember address of first match
                fAddr = res.Address
                Do
                    ' User.Offset(,9 + k) gives you column J for k=0, K for k=1, L for k=2
                    user.Offset(, 9 + k).Value = res.Offset(, -3).Value
                    ' Increment k
                    k = k + 1
                    ' Find next match
                    Set res = rng.FindNext(res)
                    ' If nothing found, exit, stop searching entries for current user
                    If res Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                ' If we already found 3 matches, then stop searching for current user
                Loop While fAddr <> res.Address And k < 3
                ' Update column headers
                sh1.Cells(1, 10).Value = "Hostname1"
                sh1.Cells(1, 11).Value = "Hostname2"
                sh1.Cells(1, 12).Value = "Hostname3"
            End If
        Next user
    End With
End Sub
```

Now if I wanted to also copy across whatever is in column A on drs.xlsx to column R on main.xlsm for every match found (ignoring any further matches, only the first host for a particular user) so that the column is not overwritten), how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the code before the `do loop`, where you `' Remember address of first match`.

```
user.Offset(0, 17).Value = res.Offset(0, -4).Value
```

Comment: +1 there was no need to do it in the loop as I suggested; I'll excuse my oversight by saying it adds the option to use subsequent host by changing the `If k = x` :)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be as straight forward as adding the following after `k = k +1`:

```
If k = 1 Then
    user.Offset(,17).Value = res.Offset(, -4).Value
End If
```

If k = 1 then it is the first time it has found the match so copy over column A